# Android Bluetooth SPP connections problems

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I'am trying to write an app that communicates over Bluetooth SPP using an "Brainbox BL-819" adapter. (http://www.brainboxes.com/product/bl-819/bluetooth-to-rs232-serial-adapter-1-port-male)

I've tried to get the adapter to work on different devices. On my Sony Xperia Z3 the connection almost never works. On my Motorola Moto E the connections works better but also not every time. Here is the logcat output of my Sony device:

```
10-24 14:14:30.575: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CA_ErtmConnectReq()  PSM: 0x0001  BDA: 000a4f01367e  p_ertm_info: 0x00000000 allowed:0x0 preferred:0
10-24 14:14:30.922: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_acl_role_changed: BDA: 00-0a-4f-01-36-7e
10-24 14:14:30.922: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_acl_role_changed: New role: 1
10-24 14:14:31.061: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_acl_created hci_handle=12 link_role=1  transport=1
10-24 14:14:31.061: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_acl_created hci_handle=12 link_role=1  transport=1
10-24 14:14:31.061: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CAP - st: CLOSED evt: 0
10-24 14:14:31.061: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CAP - st: ORIG_W4_SEC_COMP evt: 7
10-24 14:14:31.071: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_read_remote_version_complete: BDA: 00-0a-4f-01-36-7e
10-24 14:14:31.071: W/bt-btm(19371): btm_read_remote_version_complete lmp_version 2 manufacturer 10 lmp_subversion 1503
10-24 14:14:31.071: W/bt-btif(19371): info:x0
10-24 14:14:31.071: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CA_SetDesireRole() new:x0, disallow_switch:0
10-24 14:14:31.072: D/(19371): remote version info [00:0a:4f:01:36:7e]: 2, a, 5df
10-24 14:14:31.088: I/BTConnectionReceiver(10482): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=00:0A:4F:01:36:7E, alias=null, name=Brainboxes RS232 Adapter, majorDeviceClass=1280, deviceClass=1280]
10-24 14:14:31.090: I/BluetoothClassifier(10482): Bluetooth Device Name: Brainboxes RS232 Adapter
10-24 14:14:31.153: E/bt-btm(19371): Ignoring RNR as the state is not BTM_SEC_STATE_GETTING_NAME
10-24 14:14:33.578: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CAP - st: W4_L2CAP_CON_RSP evt: 19
10-24 14:15:33.588: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CAP - st: W4_L2CAP_CON_RSP evt: 32
10-24 14:15:33.589: W/bt-sdp(19371): SDP - Rcvd conn cnf with error: 0xeeee  CID 0x45
10-24 14:15:33.589: E/bt-btif(19371): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:5, failed to find channle,                                       status:1, scn:0
10-24 14:15:33.590: W/bt-btif(19371): invalid rfc slot id: 5
10-24 14:15:37.692: E/bt-btm(19371): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
10-24 14:15:37.692: W/bt-l2cap(19371): L2CA_SetDesireRole() new:x0, disallow_switch:0
10-24 14:15:37.701: D/BluetoothMapService(19371): onReceive
10-24 14:15:37.701: D/BluetoothMapService(19371): onReceive, action android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
10-24 14:15:37.723: I/BTConnectionReceiver(10482): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=00:0A:4F:01:36:7E, alias=null, name=Brainboxes RS232 Adapter, majorDeviceClass=1280, deviceClass=1280]
10-24 14:15:37.726: I/BluetoothClassifier(10482): Bluetooth Device Name: Brainboxes RS232 Adapter
```

Is this a known problem and how can I fix this?